# Show half of rotating image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am creating an animation where a circle is rotating (left image).

My goals is only having half of the animation visible (blue rectangle in right image). In web development I would have created a div with a hidden overflow. I can't get this to work in Flutter. I've looked into [ClipRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html) without luck.

[image]

This is the Flutter code I am using to rotate the image:

```
class ImageRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageRotate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageRotateState createState() => _ImageRotateState();
}

class _ImageRotateState extends State<ImageRotate>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 30),
    );

    animationController.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      // color: Colors.white,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Image.asset('assets/svg/circle.png'),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? _widget) {
          return Transform.rotate(
            angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a **Stack** that clips its contents using its **clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge** option, then you shift it half way its height. You wrap the **Stack** in a **SizedBox** to constrain its height to half the height of the circle, and apply a height to the ImageRotate also, as such:

```dart
Center(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    child: Stack(
       clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
       children: [
         Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: ImageRotate()
         )
       ]
    )
 ),
)
```

To your **ImageRotate**:

```dart
SizedBox(
   child: Image.asset('assets/svg/circle.png', width: 400, height: 400, fit: BoxFit.contain)
),
```

Check out this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/6653c8a5944feccb154b15736d2fc113) and run it through DartPad.dev to check it out. Your output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I really like the few lines of codes needed to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea,

1. Put your circle and a rectangular opaque box(possibly container) in a Stack Widget in this order.
2. Give the container half of your rectangular box's size and color that can hide the circle.
3. Wrap the container in Positioned Widget and place it aligning to the bottom half of the blue rectangle.

   ```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Stack(children: [
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: animationController,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/download.png',
                  width: 400,
                  height: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? _widget) {
                return Transform.rotate(
                  angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
                  child: _widget,
                );
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
   }
   ```

In this code:

1. I used ClipOval for circular image cause my image was square.
2. Parent container has height and width, as well as child positioned container(half of the parent height).
3. And SafeArea for avoiding device margins.

Is this what you're looking for?